# Two-column Match with VBA variables

Tags: vba, excel, match

I've been stuck at this line of code in my macro for a week now and read and tried numerous methods at solving this.

I must declare that I'm not very good with VBA so bear with me and I'd appreciate a token explanation of some of the steps.

What I want to do is rather simple actually, I have a large database of about 1000 rows in a table which I would like to do a match for two columns (with duplicates) for the same row number as efficiently as possible, for example:

Column #1 : James, John, John, James, Jeb

column #2 : Smith, Lee, Smith, Wills, Black

I would like to find the row with "John" & "Smith" and the simple answer would be row #3.

But the added complication is that the match target is a variable, for e.g.

```
dim name1 as string
dim name2 as string
dim r as long
name1 = "John"
name2 = "Smith"
r = application.worksheetfunction.match(name1&name2,.range("A:A")&.range("B:B"),0)
```

Where this function has to be repeated through many iterations in the macro.

I've tried for instance using the for i=1 to 1000 and individually matching for both columns through if arguments, but as far as I understand I couldn't get the row number out of the loop, ie r = result.row becomes empty outside the loop.

Thank you very much for reading through this! This forum has contributed so much to my existing code and I'm incredibly grateful to the help so far.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do something similar earlier this week, and while the issue looks daunting, reading through posts on here and other locations gave a rather simple but easy solution.

Step 1:
In your spreadsheet, in Column C, insert the following formula

```
=CONCATENATE(A1&B1)
```

Copy and paste this down for all cells in A and B.

Step 2:
Your VBA code looks good. However, you need some way to print the result to somewhere. You can either print to a message box

```
=msgbox(r)
```

or to the sheet

eg. `Range("XX) = r`

These should hopefully solve your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Persist the value of 'r' which is being returned by Match() in an array. Later, use the array for further action.